# Book of three short stories with gay themes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this book at least 8 years ago. It had a red cover with an angel?(I'm not sure) on it. If I'm not wrong it had three short stories, all with gay themes. One had something to do with an angel and the other one had something to do with a male thief, a female weather druid or warlock. In the end the thief and druid married so he can continue to have a relationship with another guy and so she can practice her magic in peace.

Comment: There's a surprising amount of [LGBT speculative fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LGBT-themed_speculative_fiction) out there. Anything sound familiar? Also any idea of how old this book/stories might be?

Comment: The one with the angel could be Tom Reamy's [*Under the Hollywood Sign*](http://www.amazon.com/San-Diego-Lightfoot-Tom-Reamy/dp/0441749569)

Comment: Not all that surprising, actually. School librarians have a history of using the general public's misunderstanding of the SFF genre (Oh, Yeah, all that star wars stuff) to sneak in books with themes and ideas that would otherwise be restricted.